# Objective-C method pointer send message

Tags: objective-c, methods, fractions

I am new to obj-c programming, I read Kochan's book.

here is code from book

```
-(void) add:(Fraction *) f 
{
  numerator = numerator *f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator
  denominator = numerator * f.denominator

}
```

I know the 'f' is point to Fraction, but I dont understand inside method that why using f.numerator or f.denominator.

Is anyone can explain it for me? my first language is not english. so please make it simple.

**Edit** :well,in math we using (a/b)+(c/d) =(ad+bc)/(bd), I know this formula. I just dont get it that why after asterisk why put f dot something.I want to know f point to where.

**EDIT**2

I still have litte problem about words in Parentheses which "(Fraction *)f"

In the book says "This says that argument to the add:method is a reference to an object from the Fraction class"

does the Fraction in that parentheses is point to Fraction class ? or the word "f" is point to Fraction class?

I dont understand this sentence. Can you give me more detail about that?

**EDIT 3**

inside add method. why using the just one f dot something?
I mean looks this

`numerator = numerator *f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator`

why we can not write code like this part.

`numerator = f.numerator *f.denominator + f.denominator * f.numerator`

I dont understand this part.

Thanks.

Comment: Why they're using it? Because they need it for the maths to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a public property on the `Fraction` class. `f` is an instance of the `Fraction` class. `numerator` and `denominator` are public properties in the `Fraction` class. The dot notation is equivalent to `[f numerator]`.

*EDIT*

Here is the rewritten code using the alternate message sending syntax.

```
-(void) add:(Fraction *) f 
{
  denominator = numerator * [f denominator];
  numerator = numerator * [f denominator] + denominator * [f numerator];
}
```

*EDIT* 2. The Fraction class header probably looks something like this.

```
class Fraction : NSObject

// methods
// ...

@property (nonatomic, strong) int numerator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) int denominator;

// other properties
// ...

end
```

Comment: can you rewrite code without by using the dot syntax? Thanks.

Comment: The method is named `add:` (the colon meaning it takes an argument) and takes the argument f which is an instance of the class `Fraction`. `Fraction *` inside of the parentheses is the type of `f`. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I know after **add:** is an argument, but I still confuse about 'f'. f is point to fraction class? and this part "(Fraction*) f" is argument for add: method? is that right?

Comment: Fraction * inside of the parentheses is the type of f.
what type? is invar ?

Comment: (Fraction *)F 
F is point Fraction class which is instance variable, and whole argument is belong to the add: method. is that right?

Comment: f is the actual parameter being passed into the method. It is a pointer to a Fraction object. `(Fraction *) f` is (type) variable. f is an object of the class Fraction therefore it's type is Fraction (ADT, Abstract Data Type). It is not an instance variable.

Comment: Take a look at these Documents. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/assignments/Walkthrough%20iOS%205_0.pdf http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1

Comment: Hi,Thanks Chris, I made some update,would you mind help me one more time?

Comment: He's actually adding another Fraction to the current Fraction instance so he is getting a common denominator for the current Fraction and the other Fraction passed into the method. The code for it is at https://github.com/gakaki/kochan.objective-c/blob/master/src/prog7.6/Fraction.m

Answer (score 0):

`numerator` and `denominator` are two properties of `Fraction`, dot "." can be used to get and set properties by using using `f.numerato`r or `f.denominator`.